# Magento 2 - Add autofill in Braintree Credit Card Form

Tags: magento2, payment, checkout, braintree, credit-card

For faster checkout process, Chrome has a feature to add autofill for credit cards like: [https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutZ6.png)

```
<label for="frmNameCC">Name on card</label>
<input name="ccname" id="frmNameCC" required placeholder="Full Name" autocomplete="cc-name">

<label for="frmCCNum">Card Number</label>
<input name="cardnumber" id="frmCCNum" required autocomplete="cc-number">

<label for="frmCCCVC">CVC</label>
<input name="cvc" id="frmCCCVC" required autocomplete="cc-csc">

<label for="frmCCExp">Expiry</label>
<input name="cc-exp" id="frmCCExp" required placeholder="MM-YYYY" autocomplete="cc-exp">
```

We just want to do the same in Magento2 Braintree Credit Card Form:
Default shows like following:

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" class="number" data-braintree-name="number" name="credit-card-number" id="credit-card-number" maxlength="22">
```

Where we need to add element autocomplete="cc-number".

[[1]: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutZ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save user's card details only, there is an option of **vault Enabled** in the basic setting in Braintree configuration which will save user's/Customer's credit/debit card details and can increase the checkout speed. 
In Magento admin panel => Store => Configuration=> Sale => Payment method => Braintree=> Basic setting .
You can check with that option too.